# ruby sqlite3 sinatra cant do db:Migrate

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sinatra

Im working on w10 64bits

## app.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require "sinatra/activerecord"
require 'sqlite3/sqlite3_native'


class App < Sinatra::Base
  #configuraciones
  set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
  set :session_secret, 'super secret'
  set :public_folder, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/public'
  set :layout, 'views/layouts'
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => 'sqlite3',
    :database =>  'data.db'
  )
  enable :sessions
  #before all requests
  before do
    headers['server'] = 'Ruby, Ubuntu'
  end

end
```

## rakefile.rb

```
require "sinatra/activerecord/rake"
require 'sqlite3/sqlite3_native'
require 'sinatra'
require './app'
```

## gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "sinatra"
gem "json"
gem 'sinatra-activerecord', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.9'
gem 'rake'
gem 'sqlite3'
```

so when i try to do db:migrate i cant do it, sqlite3 version 1.3.13
execute command

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
C:/ruby/sinatra/Rakefile.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

so i dont know what is exactly the problem need help

## UPDATE

I change in rakefile.rb for only require 'sqlite3'
but know i get other error

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
C:/ruby/sinatra/Rakefile.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/2.5/sqlite3_native
C:/ruby/sinatra/Rakefile.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `sqlite3_native` from your `rakefile.rb` and just require `sqlite3`